# DropDownList selected index change firing twice

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, event-handling, dropdown

This one is interesting.  I have a dropdown that once selected goes and runs a data call, returns the data and populates some labels on the page.  Here is the problem:

If I type to the selection and hit ENTER, the method fires once, just fine.  If I use the mouse to scroll to the selection and choose it that way, it fires twice.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPattern"  CssClass="dropdownint" runat="server" DataTextField="Pattern" DataValueField="Pattern"
                            AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddPattern_SelectedIndexChanged" EnableViewState="true" />
```

Code behind:

```
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("StoredProcedure", sc);
        sda.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pattern", Pattern.ToString());
        sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fac", this.ddfac.SelectedItem.Value);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        sda.Fill(ds);

        this.lnkInventory.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString() + " (" + ds.Tables[1].Rows[0][0].ToString() + ")";
```

There is more to the code behind but it is really just populating more labels.  I have tried many things, including setting the AutoEventWireup="false", and making sure I had no src in any tags, and even unsubscribing the event every time, but none of that works.  And it is really weird how it just fires once if I type the selection but twice if I mouse select.

Comment: Are you double clicking with the mouse by any chance?

Comment: Are you also attaching an event handler in the code behind, in addition to the declared one you've shown?

Comment: No, I am not.  I thought of that, but if I was, it should be doubling up no matter how I select the dropdown

Comment: Things that I can think of that might do this:

1.) Multiple form tags.
2.) Jquery front-end code for .change() event on dropdown.
3.) Multiple or nested UpdatePanel items.
4.) Jquery that fires when element that dropdown is contained in that submits the form.
5.) Any "AutoPostBack" item that the dropdown is contained in.

Comment: I am going to add to the wierdness.   My dropdown list contains 100 items or so.  If I choose an item at the top, the query runs instantaneously.  If I choose an item at the botton, the code runs twice and takes forever.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  Was due to a try catch problem that wasn't being handled properly and causing a duplication error on certain items that were chosen.

Answer (score 0):

**This is perfectally work for my project when unschedule visit show a div**

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="txtvisitname" AutoPostBack="true" class="txtno" AppendDataBoundItems="true" 
                runat="server" onchange="return selectChange()">
                <asp:ListItem Text="--SELECT--" Value="0" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="VISIT1" Value="VISIT1" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="VISIT2" Value="VISIT2" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="VISIT3" Value="VISIT3" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="VISIT4" Value="VISIT4" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="VISIT5" Value="VISIT5" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="Unscheduled  VISIT" Value="Unscheduled  VISIT" />
            </asp:DropDownList>
```

```
function selectChange() {        
      if ($("[id*=txtvisitname]").val() == "Unscheduled  VISIT") {
             $(".other").show();
         } else {
             $(".other").hide();
      }
 }
```